# Returning a single projection from native query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to return a projection, not a list of projections, from a native query. I keep running into a converter error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [PersonRepository$NameProjection]
```

My spring version is fairly old (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa v1.5.3), but I can't upgrade it for external reasons. So I was just wondering if I could make it work with the version I have.

My repository looks like this:

```java
public PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {

    interface NameProjection {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
    }

    @Query(value = "SELECT first_name AS firstName, last_name AS lastName FROM person where person_id = :personId", nativeQuery = true)
    NameProjection getPersonNameById(@Param("personId") Integer personId);

    @Query(value = "SELECT first_name AS firstName, last_name AS lastName FROM person", nativeQuery = true)
    List<NameProjection> getPersonNames();
}
```

When I call `getPersonNameById()`, I get the error above. What's interesting is that method works if I change my projection to have only 1 field, let's say `firstName`. However, whenever there is more than one field, I get the converter error above.

Calling `getPersonNames()` works exactly like I expect where a list of the projections are returned with the fields I specified.

How can I change my repository code so that Spring will allow me to return a single projection?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a long fixed bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-980 or some related issue, there have been a few in that area.

If you happen to use EclipseLink there are even still issues with this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525319

So the real fix for this is to upgrade your versions.

If that isn't possible as you describe in your question probably the best idea is to switch to a custom implementation and work with the `EntityManager` or even just a Jdbc `Connection`/`JdbcTemplate` directly.

Comment: Ah that issue seems to describe my problem exactly! Unfortunately, the project I'm working on is not in a good position to be upgraded to a newer spring data version currently. I am using a workaround of returning a list of the projection and just getting the first element in the list and that is working well for me now.
Thank you for the reply! It was hard to find answers to this even after googling!